# replace standard javascript onclick with jquery click on buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is some code that I am using to add preventDefault to all my existing legacy onlick code, replacing it with JQuery. It seems to work, but can you think of any problems with it. We plan to move fully to jQuery, but this is just an interum fix. Is there a quicker or cleaner was to do this?

```
<html>
    <head><title>Test</title>
    <script src="includes/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js?t=20130606"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <form name="testing">

    <script>
        var robtesting = 100;

        </script>

    <button id="test">0</button>
    <button onclick="alert('1');">1</button>
     <button onclick="alert(this.form.tagName); alert(robtesting); ">1</button>
    <button >2</button>
    </form>
    <script>


     jQuery('#test').click(function(){
        alert('0');    
     });

         jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('button').each(function(){
        var button = jQuery(this);
        var hasclick = button.attr("onclick")
        var hasJQueryClick = false;
        var eventsObject = button.data("events");
        if(typeof eventsObject != 'undefined'){
            jQuery.each(eventsObject, function(i, e) {
                if(i == 'click'){
                    hasJQueryClick = true;
                }
            });
        }

        if(typeof hasclick == 'function'){
            button.removeAttr("onclick");
            button.click(function(event){
               event.preventDefault();
               this.tryItOutRob = hasclick;
               this.tryItOutRob();
            });
        } else if(!hasJQueryClick) {
           button.click(function(event){
               event.preventDefault();
           });
        }

    });
}) ;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution is ok ,there will be no problem

Comment: Where is tryItOutRob() function defined ?

Comment: You should ask this question in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: the function is created on this line this.tryItOutRob = hasclick;

Answer (score 0):

It does work but that's an extra workload for JavaScript every time the page is loaded. I would suggest printing the whole updated HTML out and replacing the old one with it.

Comment: the problem for me is it is all PHP generated code, and we have probably 500 instances of this legacy javascript code.

Comment: Could you be able to do the removing of those onclick-attributes with PHP? Then the workload would be mostly server-sided.

Comment: Interesting idea ... could probably write a script that could parse the php file and then add a jquery onclick event after the button. e.g. <button onclick="test(); return false;"></button> to <button id="abc"></button><script>jQuery('#abc').click(function(){ test(); return false })</script>